# how to pass a value to another page using onsen UI

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Hello i am newbie to onsenUI and angular js,I found a function "pushpage" for navigate to another page,But i have searched since two days in how to pass a value to another page ,Please help me to figure out this as i have wasted 2 days in this..:( my code is

```
                      Content =
                              '<ons-button onclick=gallery.pushPage("dishes.html");>'
  +data['Details'][i]['varName'] +  data['Details'][i]['intGlCode'] +'<br>'+   
  '</ons-button>';
                  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a value in the options argument of the `pushPage` call. Like this:

```
nav.pushPage('page.html', {value: 10});
```

You can then retrieve the value by doing:

```
console.log(nav.getCurrentPage().options.value);
```

It is not clear from your question if you're using AngularJS or some other framework for your app. If you are using AngularJS you can fetch the value in the controller of your pushed page.

You have a template or a page like this:

```
<ons-template id="page.html">
  <ons-page ng-controller="PageController">
    ...
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

And in your controller you can do like this:

```
module.controller('PageController', function($scope) {
  console.log($scope.nav.getCurrentPage().options);
});
```

If you are not using AngularJS you can get the value by waiting for the 'pageinit' event. I'll use jQuery as an example:

HTML:

```
<ons-page id="page">
  ...
</ons-page>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page', function() { 
  // Do something.
});
```

Comment: Hello thanks so much for help,yes i'm using angular js in my app,One question is raised is,is only one "ons-navigator" require to pass this values?and it should be in "index.html" page?or all the html pages required "ons-navigator" ?

Comment: Yes, generally you only need one navigator for you app, in some rare cases you might need more if your app is very complex.

Comment: So sir,After putting "ons-navogator" to index.html and removing from all other pages it fires an error "Fail to fetch PageView from ons-page element",So can you pls tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry, I need to see the code in order to solve that. Please post an example on Codepen.

Comment: its very large code,can you pls tell me the possibilities to get error "failed to fetch pageview from ons-page element"?

Comment: You are probably missing a `<ons-page>` tag.

Comment: actually i am using sliding menu,this way,ons-list class="menu-list">
  <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('food-menu.html', {closeMenu: true})">
    <ons-icon icon="fa-th-large" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon>
    Menu
  </ons-list-item>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable like in a single page application !